# ‘int main()’ previously defined here

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, c++14

I did this code and faced an error that I can't understand what it is. I run this program in VS code and compilation was successful but getting an compilation error in GFG portal.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
/*
* Create classes Rectangle and RectangleArea
*/
int l,b, result;

class Rectangle
{
   public:
      void display()
      {
        cout<<l <<" "<< b<<endl;
      }
};

class RectangleArea : public Rectangle
{
  public:
    void read_input()
    {
        cin >> l >> b;
    }
    void display()
    {
        result = l* b;
        cout<<result;
    }
};

int main()
{
 /*
 * Declare a RectangleArea object
 */
 RectangleArea r_area;

  /*
  * Read the width and height
  */
  r_area.read_input();

/*
 * Print the width and height
 */
  r_area.Rectangle::display();

  /*
  * Print the area
  */
  r_area.display();

   return 0;
  }
```

[And this is the error I got. Help me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3wql.png)

[This is the GFG problem that I'm doing.](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/rectangle-area/problem?isFullScreen=true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't paste the main function, the portal adds it again to the source so it appears twice.